# How do I stop a Nikon L28 from timing out?

Tags: nikon

It keeps timing out, I want to check something but it just turns itself off. I turn it back on and it does the same thing 30 seconds later. Where can I turn this off, if possible?

Comment: Never mind, I managed to figure it out myself. If anyone else is here who needs the answer, go to your settings under Menu and change the "Auto-off" option to your preference.

:)

Comment: you should be able to post an answer for your own question and accept it I believe.  Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

According to OP:

> Never mind, I managed to figure it out myself. If anyone else is here who needs the answer, go to your settings under Menu and change the "Auto-off" option to your preference. :)